# Which Fedora CPU architecture should I choose? i386 or i686?

Tags: fedora, system-installation, x86

I have an old Thinkpad X32 which has an `Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 1.80GHz` based on the result of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and I was wondering which is better to use on it, the `i386` or the `i686` version of the Fedora ISO found [here](http://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora-all).

Basically, I don't know how to determine if my CPU is an `i386` or an `i686`. If you could also tell me how I can get this data, please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, i686 is for Pentium Pro/II and later, while i386 covers 386 and 486 CPUs as well. From http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=198771:

> > i want to know that what is the meaning and difference between i386 and i686 specified at the end of each package..?
>
> Compiled for different CPU architectures. i386 should run fine on anything above a 386 processor. i686 is for newer Pentium processors (by new I mean PII and above), but can also be run on newer Intel Core 2 Duos, Athlons, etc.

So `i686` should work; pretty much anything newer than the Pentium Pro or Pentium II is i686.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, will `i386` run better, or as efficiently, on an `i686` machine?

Comment: Isn't a Pentium 1 a i586?

Comment: @CodeInChaos indeed. fixing my answer

Comment: @Eric if a binary is compiled for i686 a good compiler should use features that make certain steps faster than in the i386-architecture. So i386 should be slower on a Pentium.

Answer (score 2):

Look up [i686](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I686): it means P6, and

> The first implementation of the P6 core was the Pentium Pro CPU in 1995, the immediate successor to the original Pentium design (P5).

Unless your computer is an embedded device running an older i386 processor (there are a few of these, not many), or is more than 15 years old, pick i686.